# Alexa Pagerank using jquery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the alexa pagerank via http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url= + weburl
Here is the url for getting the alexa rank of facebook.com

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url=http://www.facebook.com
```

If you copy the link above and paste in your browser you can see that it is in xml format.

I am jusing getJSON to retrieve the alexa rank from other domain. I am also using yql api. you can see the url in the first parameter below.

```
var url = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url="+ inputtedURL;
```

OR to be specific

```
var url = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url=www.facebook.com";
```

Below is my getjsON

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){

       }
);
```

How will I get the contents of this http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url=http://www.facebook.com since this is in xml format. the getJSON returns JSON objects.

Any other suggestions?? I am building an alexa page rank checker using jquery only .

Comment: Don't you need to do JSONP when its crossdomain? You got dataType and converter if you use an ajax call instead. And why do you not want to process it as XML? :)

Answer (score 0):

I see I'm a bit late to the party, but I had to solve this today and thought somebody might find it useful: You can use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to convert XML data to JSON.

I created an [example Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=c43fc0ed13fc8945cf438da90bff0121) that take a 'site' parameter, passes it to Alexa's API, and returns the result.  You can simply add '_render=json' to the query and get the results back in JSON.  So using jquery...

```
var pipe = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?";
pipe += "_id=c43fc0ed13fc8945cf438da90bff0121";
pipe += "&site=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
pipe += "&_render=json&callback=?";

$.getJSON(pipe,
   function(data){

   }
);
```

(Feel free to clone the Pipe and do with it as you will.)

Here's an example call to get Alexa stats for StackOverflow in JSON:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run&_id=c43fc0ed13fc8945cf438da90bff0121&_render=json&site=http://stackoverflow.com

The prettified output looks like this:

```
{"count":1,"value":{
  "title":"AlexaData",
  "description":"Pipes Output",
  "link":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/pipe.info?_id=c43fc0ed13fc8945cf438da90bff0121",
  "pubDate":"Wed, 09 Jan 2013 21:50:25 +0000",
  "generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/",
  "callback":"",
  "items":[{
    "AID":"=","HOME":"0","URL":"stackoverflow.com\/","VER":"0.9",
    "DMOZ":{
      "SITE":{
        "BASE":"stackoverflow.com\/",
        "DESC":"A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers. Questions and answers displayed by user votes and tags.",
        "TITLE":"Stack Overflow",
        "CATS":{
          "CAT":[
            {"CID":"377304","ID":"Top\/Computers\/Programming\/Resources\/Chats_and_Forums","TITLE":"Resources\/Chats and Forums"},
            {"CID":"477752","ID":"Top\/Reference\/Ask_an_Expert\/Computers_and_Technology","TITLE":"Ask an Expert\/Computers and Technology"}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "SD":{
      "POPULARITY":{"SOURCE":"panel","TEXT":"86","URL":"stackoverflow.com\/"},
      "REACH":{"RANK":"81"},"RANK":{"DELTA":"-3"},
      "COUNTRY":{"CODE":"IN","NAME":"India","RANK":"25"}},
      "description":null,
      "title":null
    }
  ]}
}
```